# Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView

Tags: android, android-layout, exoplayer

Am really not getting what exactly not working in my code. Getting following error.

```
Process: com.example.pash.myapplication, PID: 10139
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pash.myapplication/com.example.pash.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Following is my code

Following is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.pash.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import com.example.myapplication.PreviewSeekBar;
import com.example.myapplication.PreviewSeekBarLayout;
import com.example.pash.myapplication.exoplayer.ExoPlayerManager;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener,
    Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener {

private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

private ExoPlayerManager exoPlayerManager;
private PreviewSeekBarLayout seekBarLayout;
private PreviewSeekBar seekBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

SimpleExoPlayerView playerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
SimpleExoPlayerView previewPlayerView
        = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.previewPlayerView);
seekBar = (PreviewSeekBar) playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_progress);
seekBarLayout = (PreviewSeekBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.previewSeekBarLayout);


seekBarLayout.setTintColorResource(R.color.colorPrimary);

seekBar.addOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
exoPlayerManager = new ExoPlayerManager(playerView, previewPlayerView, seekBarLayout);
exoPlayerManager.play(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.url_hls)));
seekBarLayout.setup(exoPlayerManager);

View view = previewPlayerView.getVideoSurfaceView();

if (view instanceof SurfaceView) {
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) view;
    surfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    surfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

requestFullScreenIfLandscape();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        exoPlayerManager.play(data.getData());
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    exoPlayerManager.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    exoPlayerManager.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    exoPlayerManager.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    exoPlayerManager.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    exoPlayerManager.stopPreview();
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_local) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("video/*.mp4");
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_toggle) {
        if (seekBarLayout.isShowingPreview()) {
            seekBarLayout.hidePreview();
            exoPlayerManager.stopPreview();
        } else {
            seekBarLayout.showPreview();
            exoPlayerManager.loadPreview(seekBar.getProgress(), seekBar.getMax());
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void requestFullScreenIfLandscape() {
    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.landscape)) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }
}}
```

Following is activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.pash.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exoplayer_controls"
         />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my exoplayer_controls.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.example.myapplication.PreviewSeekBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/previewSeekBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/previewFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/video_preview_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/video_preview_height"
                android:background="@drawable/video_frame"
                android:padding="@dimen/video_frame_width">


                <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
                    android:id="@+id/previewPlayerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_simple_player_view"
                    app:surface_type="surface_view"
                    app:use_artwork="false"
                    app:use_controller="false" />


            </FrameLayout>

            <com.example.myapplication.PreviewSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/previewFrameLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:max="800"
                android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:thumbTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:paddingStart="10dp" />


        </com.example.myapplication.PreviewSeekBarLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CC000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_prev"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_rew"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_next"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It showing me error in setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); this line.

Comment: Do you have `exoplayer_controls` xml file placed in your layout folder?

Comment: check your SimpleExoPlayerView class package name. SimpleExoPlayerView is not available withing your application. that is why this error comes

Comment: Are you running signed apk?

Comment: @TheTechWolf yes i having exoplayer_controls xml file

Comment: @RonakMakwana am importing it from google library so i think not a issue with SimpleExoplayerView

Comment: Remove `app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exoplayer_controls"` line and try then. If it's not crashing, then the problem is in your exoplayer_controls.xml.

Comment: @vilpe89 i have edited my question can you plz  tell me where am going wrong..?

Comment: @vilpe89 Thank you problem is in exoplayer_controls.xml i found ..now it's working like champ thank you..:)

Comment: Can you share what you have changed in your file to resolve this issue?